# Use Tooltip.js to render React Components

Tags: reactjs, popper.js

I trying to use this awesome tooltip library [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html)

I want to use the above tooltip utility to render React Components into it. Right now, my understanding is that I can only give static html to the tooltip using `title` property and `html` set to true in the config object. I tried `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` but that is again creating a static markup with no lifecycle hooks or any of the React goodness. Is there any way I can inject React Components into the tooltip? Or can you please suggest some other library like this that supports flip behaviour on viewport boundaries?

*PS: I don't want to use Popper.js or react-popper as I want the trigger functionality to work out of the box.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using react-popper package.

Answer (score 1):

On tooltip initializing you can pass a boolean prop defining your title as an HTML

```
new Tooltip(reference, {html: true, title: "<div>This is a component</div>"})
```

[See tooltip documentation](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-documentation.html)

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have tried it. This will render static html to the tooltip, not a React Component.

Comment: How to import Tooltip in the js file?